# Is there a way to show the sum of a value within a certain time range (ex: 2 days)?

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am measuring the duration in minutes of various tools. The tool can run multiple times in the same day. I would like to flag a tool as "High Use" if the tool runs for more than 20 minutes in a 2 day period. This will be shown in matrix format.

For example, I want to flag Tool A as "High Use" but not flag Tool B

I'm not sure how to indicate a 2 day time period. Is this possible to do in DAX?

| Date | Tool Name | Minutes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/2 | Tool A | 10 |
| 12/2 | Tool B | 5 |
| 12/2 | Tool C | 7 |
| 12/3 | Tool A | 12 |
| 12/3 | Tool B | 6 |

Comment: Can you explain how you want to show this measure if in your data appears the next few days for Tools?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the table name is `ToolUsage` and the Date column to be a DATETIME, it's possible to write a measure to compute the last two days usage for a single tool

```
Tool2LastDayUsage = 
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( ToolUsage[Tool Name] ),
    VAR MaxDate = MAX ( ToolUsage[Date] )
    VAR LastTwoDays =
        CALCULATETABLE (
            VALUES(ToolUsage[Date]),
            ToolUsage[Date] > MaxDate - 2
                && ToolUsage[Date] <= MaxDate
        )
    RETURN
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( ToolUsage[Minutes] ),
            LastTwoDays,
            ALLEXCEPT (
                ToolUsage,
                ToolUsage[Tool Name]
            )
        )
)
```

First we check to have a single tool selected using `HASONEVALUE`, then we compute the last date in the current selection and we use it to prepare the `LastTwoDays` table containing the 2 days period. At last we compute the last two days usage by applying the `LastTwoDays` filter table, together with `ALLEXCEPT` to remove any existing filter over the `ToolUsage` table but the filter over the `Tool Name`

Then we can use this measure to build another measure to check the last two days period usage and flag high used tools with "High Use"

```
HighUse = IF( [Tool2LastDayUsage] > 20, "Hig Use" )
```

These measures can be used in a matrix or a table visuals. If the `ToolUsage[Date]` is included, they use it to compute the last two days period.

[image: Power BI visuals with result]

Of course, different behavior may be implemented; for instance to flag the tool regardless of the date on the current visual row, using the overall max date instead.

To show a 2 period inside a visual, it may be possible to create a table with a description, like 12/2-12/3 and a date, 12/3 in this case, to be set in relationship with the ToolUsage table.